# bash re-read it's if statement and print correct info to the log

Tags: bash, if-statement, exec

So I have following problem. I want to create script, which creates action (in this example, appropriate entry in log'd be enough), after metadata of file /bin/a is changed. I am checking metadata by parsing stat output.
After that, script is using sed to take new value of metadata and I want my script to continue.

The problem is, that even if it has correct value of new time stamp in "Change" parameter from stat (new value for file /bin/a, in which for example, I have changed chmod to 754), it still produces error to the log (basically takes what is in "else" instead of what is under "if"... I hope I made myself clear enough :) Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# These lines do nothing more
# then logging STDOUT and STDERR to the log file:

exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>/var/log/rest-nscd.log 2>&1

# Script itself:

while true
do
sleep 5
CHANGE=$(stat /bin/a |grep Change |awk '{print $3}')
if [ "$CHANGE" == "22:03:09.499223862" ]; then
    echo "OK ===  $(date)"
else  sed -i "s/22:03:09.499223862/$(stat /bin/a |grep Change |awk '{print $3}')/g" /bin/reset-test.sh && echo "NOT OK" '!!!!!!'
fi
done
```

Comment: try adding trace using `set -x` before `if`

Comment: You can give options to `stat` to tell it which properties to return, so you don't have to parse with `grep` and `awk`.

Comment: e.g. `change=$(stat -c "%z" /bin/a)`